# Cross reference of siblings from a common iterface

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have something like this :

```cpp
class X
{
    method(){...};
    void f()=0;
};

class my_X;
class my_Y;

class my_X: public X
{
    public:
        his_Y* opp;
        void f()={...};
};

class his_X: public X
{
    public:
        my_X* opp;
        void f()={...};
};
```

Now when I want to take profit of polymorphism and use my member `opp` while calling `X::method()` g++ says that `opp` was not declared. Since `X` is abstract, I thought the compiler would understand that method can only be called from a `my_X` or `his_X` in which `opp` is declared.

One trick I found would be to add a member `X* opp` to my class `X` that would subsequently be hidden by my subclasses definitions of `opp`.

Is this the right solution ? If not is there a solution ? Or does this issue come from a bad class design ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible solutions

```
class X
{
    method(){... getOpp(); ...};
    virtual void f()=0;
    virtual X* getOpp() = 0;
};

class my_X;
class my_Y;

class my_X: public X
{
    public:
        his_Y* opp;
        void f()={...};
        X* getOpp() override { return opp; }
};

class his_X: public X
{
    public:
        my_X* opp;
        void f()={...};
        X* getOpp() override { return opp; }
};
```

> Since X is abstract, I thought the compiler would understand that method can only be called from a my_X or his_X in which opp is declared.

No, it can't understand that. While compiling the class X, it knows nothing about derived classes.